# What is exactly in my bash variable

Tags: bash, random

OK, to some of you this will seem pretty stupid but I am almost 100% sure I am doing things correct. No matter how hard I try, I always end up ending with "Why?"

EDIT if I let number=$(rolldice -u 1d20); echo $rolldice; run in a loop I get something like this

```
1
2
7
...
```

My question is this, is there a way to see exactly what I am getting as $number (including all white spaces and other nonsense)?

```
<code here>
number=$(rolldice -u 1d20)
case $number in
1) let "one += 1"
;;
2) let "two += 1"
;;
3) let "three += 1"
;;
4) let "four += 1"
;;
5) let "five += 1"
;;
6) let "six += 1"
;;
7) let "seven += 1"
;;
8) let "eight += 1"
;;
9) let "nine += 1"
;;
10) let "ten += 1"
;;
11) let "eleven += 1"
;;
12) let "twelve += 1"
;;
13) let "thirteen += 1"
;;
14) let "fourteen += 1"
;;
15) let "fifteen += 1"
;;
16) let "sixteen += 1"
;;
17) let "seventeen += 1"
;;
18) let "eighteen += 1"
;;
19) let "nineteen += 1"
;;
20) let "twenty += 1"
;;
*) echo Why?
    exit;
;;
<more code here>
```

It runs out I was getting number and a space. Thank you 'konsolebox' <3

Comment: `echo $number`?  Or `echo "|"$number"|"` to see where the spaces are etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use `echo`:

```
echo "|$number|"
```

Or use `hexdump` so you can exactly see what form of white spaces you get:

```
echo -n "$number" | hexdump -C
```

`-n` prevents adding newline in the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using an array:

```
declare -a count
for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do
    number=$(rolldice -u 1d20)
    ((count[number]++))
done

for idx in "${!count[@]}"; do
    printf "%3d: %d\n" $idx ${count[idx]}
done
```